# Negating a number in VHDL using least logic

Tags: vhdl

I want to do something like this:

```
variable a, b (both signed)
variable error (signed also)

if (a is positive) 
    b = error
else
    b = -error
```

So far I have something like this:

```
if (a(a'high) = '0') then
    b <= error;
else
    b <= -1 * error;
end if;
```

But this doesn't work because the multiplication makes the RHS a larger width.

What is the best way to attack this? I could write a function to do a 2's complement negation and use this, but I'm also rather worried about the effect on timing requirements.

Comment: Regardless of width issues, that can be trivially fixed, you do not want to sacrifice a hardware multiplier to do this.

Comment: Why worry about least logic? The synthesis tool knows how to optimize.

Comment: @BrianCarlton: If you prefer, read this question as "how can I specify this behavior in such a way that the synthesis tool produces optimal logic".

Comment: RE: Bit extension: What do you want it to do with the maximal negative number?  The +ve equivalent can't be represented in the same number of bits...

Comment: @MartinThompson: Good point regarding the maximal negative number. However it should be OK, as if things have got that high (32767), then there are bigger issues.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
variable a: signed(7 downto 0);
variable error: signed(a'range);
variable b: unsigned(a'range);

if a < 0 then
  b:=-error;
else
  b:=error;
end if;
```

However you do it, the logic should end up the same (even if you multiply by -1, I'd hope the synth is smart enough to notice and just stick a set of LUTs and a carry chain in there!)

Answer (score 1):

```
begin 

     b <= not(error) + "00000001"; 

end
```

There are some edge cases, watch out, read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Calculating_two.27s_complement) carefully.

I believe you know it but I'll mention it just in case. bits are bits and the interpretation of them is made by the user, it can be a picture, signal, number, positive number etc. most `FPGAs` treats numbers as 2's complement.

Comment: Can't you just cast it to a signed and use the unary minus?